# netbeans how to take from two textfields the fixed values and add them to a third with buttons?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
/*code inside of 1st button*/
private void btn1......{
double a1,a2,result;

a1=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
a2=Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());

result=a1+a2;

jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));}

/*code inside of 2nd button*/
private void btn2......{
double a1,a2,result;

a1=Double.parseDouble(jTextField4.getText());
a2=Double.parseDouble(jTextField5.getText());

result=a1+a2;

jTextField6.setText(String.valueOf(result));}

/*code inside of 3rd button*/
private void btn3......{
double a1,a2,result;

a1=Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
a2=Double.parseDouble(jTextField6.getText());

result=a1+a2;

jTextField7.setText(String.valueOf(result));}
```

So i am adding 2 numbers with the first button and another two with the second button and i want with a third button to take the sum of them but when i click on 3rd button doesn't show anything on textfield why?

Comment: it's hard to say, since we can only base ourself on 'approximately what the code is' snippets. are you sure that jTextField3 and jTextField6 contain text?

Comment: And the sum textfields contain correct values?

Comment: Add some more problem details,what does first and second button print,etc!!!

Comment: i accidentally wrote the answer without knowing. i had my textfields putting numeric values and not text like @Stultuske said.Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that using Double.valueOf(String str) works smoother. Perhaps try that.
Then when you put it into a field as text, just field.setText("" + doubleNum);

Of course, this will all go to the dogs if the values in the text fields are not actually numbers... so perhaps add some error checking for that?

Answer (score 3):

why do u have a '.' operator after parseDouble? 
a2=Double.parseDouble.(jTextField2.getText());

Correcting that would help.. gud luck

Comment: The remaining code with that particular error removed worked for me. I got output on clicking button3.

Comment: just a typo.thnx for mentioning

Comment: does the problem remain?